# Android Error when merging Dynamic Feature manifest

Tags: android-manifest, aapt, dynamic-feature

I have added a dynamic feature to a project and it is giving me an `AAPT` error when trying to run the instrumentation tests.

The project has 3 product flavors:

- development
- preproduction
- production

In the `build.gradle` of the dynamic module, I have put the flavors and compiles everything correctly. But trying to run the instrumentation tests gives me this error:

```
<dynamic-feature-route>/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/development/debug/manifestMerger2359481887313534357.xml:7:5-9:19: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka <dynamic-feature-package-name>.test:string/app_name) not found.
```

I've tried several things, but I don't find out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was actually very easy...

It has been as simple as overriding the `app_name` in each flavor of the `build.gradle` dynamic module.

```
productFlavors {
    development {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Foo App Name·dev"
    }

    preproduction {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Foo App Name·pre"
    }

    production {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Foo App Name"
    }
}
```